# I can't insert a record in database: "Invalid Column Name"

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[pro_InsertRecord]

      @table      varchar(30)   , 
      @field      varchar(max)  ,
      @value      varchar(max)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

BEGIN

 EXEC('INSERT INTO ' + @table + '(' + @field + ') VALUES ( '+ @value +')')

END
```

I can't insert a record in database but i receive an insert error message as "Invalid Column Name"

**my code:**

```
string fieldnames = "Login_UserName, Login_Password, Login_Role_Id";
```

---

```
  string fieldvalues =  UserName +"','" + Password + "'," + Role ;
```

---

```
com.Common.InsertRecord("Login", fieldnames, fieldvalues);
```

Comment: `Login_Sataus` pretty sure thats wrong, `Login_FirstName, Login_LastName, login_firstname` is one firstname too much. `Login_Mai` seams a bit too short

Comment: Add table structure for `Login`

Comment: Sometimes you may get error messages that are useless, but I guess *this* error message says it all.

Comment: In your stored proc, print out the concatenated SQL to see what you are executing. Then copy/paste it into a query window (e.g. in SSMS) and execute it manually to find your error. as others have posted, you have some dodgy column names but we cannot tell what is the error without the schema for the "login" table.

Comment: looks better now, you still miss `'`before username. write `= "'" + UserName + "'," ...`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
string fieldvalues =  UserName +"','" + Password + "'," + Role ;
```

use

```
string fieldvalues = "'" + UserName + "','" + Password + "'," + Role ;
```